# Multiple ways of initiating the same object using Spring's @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have one Spring project but it has two build configurations:

1. WAR build to be run on a Tomcat container
2. Standalone executable JAR

So I have separate context/servlet XMLs for each of them to tell how I want to initialise the beans.

1. With the WAR build, I have something like this for my `@Autowired` annotations

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.package.my"/>
   ```
2. With the standalone executable JAR, I have this instead

   ```
   <context:annotation-config/>
   ```

So here is the problem. I want to add a new class that extends the `PrintStream` class. Like this:

```
package com.package.my;
import java.io.PrintStream;
...
@Component
public class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream { ... }
```

However, I want to initialize `MyPrintStream` differently for WAR build and JAR build.

- For WAR build, I want to initialize it in this fashion (if doing it without `@Autowired`):

  ```
  MyPrintStream myPrintStream = new PrintStream(new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream(), true, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
  ```
- For JAR build, I just want to do it like this (if doing it without `@Autowired`):

  ```
  MyPrintStream myPrintStream = System.out;
  ```

If I have to do these on context/servlet XML for `@Autowired`, how can I initialize the object differently?

Note: Not sure if I am thinking this in the right way. Please correct me if I am wrong. Other opinions are also welcome.

Comment: You could try to use a factory method, e.g. in a configuration class, that returns a different stream based on some configuration property which you then set in the different builds.

Comment: do you use different spring profiles? Then just use `@Profile` annotation to provide different instances